# How to make code run similarly for rows below

Tags: excel, vba

How do I enable my code to do similar for proceeding rows, i.e For Consolidated View Range B8, extract from Big City View Range "B31", Medium City View Range "B31", Small City View Range "B31".

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim rLaunch As Range, c As Long

    'table showing monthly total launches of small, medium and large cities
    Set rLaunch = Worksheets("Launch").Range("C2").CurrentRegion
    'remove headings so we just have numbers
    Set rLaunch = rLaunch.Offset(, 2).Resize(, rLaunch.Columns.Count - 2)

    'loop through each column of table (months)
    For c = 1 To rLaunch.Columns.Count
        'Revenue
        'multiply small number by small revenue and add to same for medium and large
        For d = 1 To c
            a = a + _
                rLaunch(1, d) * Worksheets("Big City View").Range("B30").Offset(, (c + 1 - d)) + _
                rLaunch(2, d) * Worksheets("Medium City View").Range("B30").Offset(, (c + 1 - d)) + _
                rLaunch(3, d) * Worksheets("Small City View").Range("B30").Offset(, (c + 1 - d))
        Next d
        Worksheets("Consolidated View").Range("B7").Offset(, c).Value = a
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets("Big City View").Range("B30").Offset(1, 0)`

Comment: @FaneDuru when do i plug this code in? i.e. after which line of code? bear in mind, B30's 1 row offset's corresponding consolidated view will be in B8, B30's 2 row offset's corresponding consolidated view will be in B9 etc.

Comment: I extracted that line from your code. It depends of what you need to do with it. Practically,  it is equivalent with `Worksheets("Big City View").Range("B31")`. I am not sure I understand what you mean... If you need to apply exactly the rule for "B30", then you copy the existing rows and just remove "B30" with "B30". But do you understand the logic of Offset used in your existing formula? Do you need exactly the same Offset, but referencing "B30"? You can use also the existing way, but replacing `Range("B30").Offset(, (c + 1 - d))` with `Range("B30").Offset(1, (c + 1 - d))`. 1 = one row down.

Comment: Do you need the For d = 1 To c loop because 'a' contains previous months values and are therefor being added repeatedly. Also for example, if c = 6 and d loops from 1 to 6 then when d=1 you add  rLaunch(1, 1) * Range("B30").Offset(, 6) because c+1-d = 6. Is this correct ?